# jquery autocomplete not showing data for loaded result

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am working with jquery autocomplete problem I am facing right now is if I am using that with pre-loaded data it is not showing suggestions but I am making ajax call it is working fine my data is JSON objects like this way

```
[{label:"1" value:"ORg1"},label": "2" value :"org2"]
```

and my autocompelete jquery like this

```js
$(function() {
$("#searchByText").autocomplete({
  source:orgData
     })

});

function loadAllHotels(){
 

 $.ajax({
  url:"../organization/loadOrgs.htm",
  dataType:"json",
  
  success:function(data){
   orgData=data;
  }
 })
 
}
```

but if I make ajax calls from autocomplete it is working.can anyone please let me know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works,

```
var orgData = [{
    "label": "1",
    "value": "ORg1"
}, {
    "label": "2",
    "value": "org2"
}];

$(function() {
    $("#searchByText").autocomplete({
        source:function(request, response) {
            var rows = autocompleteJSONParse(orgData);
            return response(rows);
        }
    });
});

function autocompleteJSONParse(data){
    var rows = [];
    var rowData = null;
    var dataLength = data.length;   
    for(var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        rowData = data[i];
        rows[i] = {
            label: rowData.label,
            value: rowData.value
        };
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: WeDev: but my problem is I do not want to make ajax call every time I want to load whole data once and autocomplete trigger on that data

Comment: In that case, initialize autocomplete within the success callback of the AJAX method instead of DOM ready.

Comment: I tried that I wrapped autocomplete into a function called it after AJAX call but now my autocomplete not tirggerring

Comment: I just noticed the URL "../organization/loadOrgs.htm". Autocomplete is expecting information in JSON format, make sure you are getting the valid JSON data in return and check for the errors in console. Can you share fiddle link?